# should we need to release viewcontroller's object after pushing into navigation controller?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

here is sample code.

```
if(MyPageViewControllerObj==nil)
    {
        MyPageViewController *vController = [[MyPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPageView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.MyPageViewControllerObj=vController;
        [vController release];
        noOfWrongAnswers=0;
        noOfRightAnswers=0;
    }
    MyPageViewControllerObj.sessionid=sessionid;
    MyPageViewControllerObj.categoryID = categoryId;
    MyPageViewControllerObj.flashcardIdforcount = flashcardid;
    MyPageViewControllerObj.categoryType=categoryType;
    MyPageViewControllerObj.indexViewControllerobj=self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:MyPageViewControllerObj animated:YES];
```

do i need to write this line ****[MyPageViewControllerObj release]****

after pushing it into navigation controller.and also in dealloc method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should to release your `MyPageViewControllerObj` as the `UINavigationController` retains it. It does not need to be in the `-dealloc` method.

Comment: thanks for you answer also tell me does this line effects anything
in dealloc method
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: When you pop the view controller, the reference count will be reduced. If it's zero (which it probably will be) it will get dealloc'd automatically. There is no need to add it to any dealloc method directly. Suggest you read up on Objective C memory management. It's pretty easy when you get the hang of it.